# Why is Google Chrome so slow when searching from the address bar?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

I'm using the latest dev version of Google Chrome (17.0.963.6 dev) on OS X Lion (because I heard the latest version works better with Lion).

I've cleared my cache and history, but when I search from the address bar it is very slow - perhaps 5 - 6 seconds before it will pull up a result. I've unchecked the boxes for the extra features in the preference pane, but that doesn't seem to help:

[image]

When I search from the search box in Safari it is almost instantaneous, so I know it's not my internet connection. How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have this issue too and would like to know something about it.

Comment: @KishorNanda - I used the wrench icon » about chrome and it said there was a slightly newer (point) version. I downloaded it via http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=mac and it seems to be working a little better - at least for the moment.

Comment: Isn't this why they are called Dev versions, a bit buggy?

Comment: @Moab - yes but unfortunately the "stable" version for lion is actually not all that stable.

Comment: Does it also happen with a new user account?

Comment: @DanielBeck - seems like when I first open Chrome it is OK, but then after using it for a while it slows down. I don't think restarting Chrome helps, although restarting the computer might. I will try a new user account and see if that affects it.